# wordpress wp_Query pagination with custom post_type issue

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to make pagination for result of two post types which is one custom post type `question` and the normal `post`
first of all when I show all result `without pagination` using `'posts_per_page' => -1;` the function works fine

[image]

but the problem happen when I try to make pagination, as you can see pagination function works normally except the some last pages of the pagination (I guess which contains question post_type even recent post type of questions appears normally )

[image]

[image]

[image]

**here you are my full code**

```
 <?php

    $my_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => array('question', 'post'),
            'posts_per_page' => get_option('to_count_portfolio'), // -1 to show all results
            'author' => $post->post_author,
            'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
        )
    );


?>
<?php 
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();
?>

<span class="title">
    <?php echo get_post_type(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</span>
<br />

<?php endwhile;  ?>  
<?php 
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links(
        array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total' => $my_query->max_num_pages
        )
    );
?>
```

**How can I make pagination work normally and navigate to all pagination links ?**

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code this:

```
 <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    if ($paged == "1") {
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('question', 'post'),
            'posts_per_page' => get_option('to_count_portfolio'), // -1 to show all results
            'author' => $post->post_author,
            'offset' => 0
    );
} else {
    $offset = $paged * 5;
    $offset = $offset - 5;
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => array('question', 'post'),
            'posts_per_page' => get_option('to_count_portfolio'), // -1 to show all results
            'author' => $post->post_author,
            'offset' => $offset
    );
}

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php 
    if ($loop->have_posts()) :while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>

<span class="title">
    <?php echo get_post_type(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>
</span>
<br />

<?php endwhile;  ?>  
<div class="pagination-grp">
    <?php
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    //$i=1;

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'prev_text' => __('<'),
        'next_text' => __('>'),
        'total' => $loop->max_num_pages

    ));
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Arpan I change my code with yours, but I still getting same 404 last for the page

Answer (score 1):

```
install this free plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/
then refer below code

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'post',
    'cat'                    => '53',
    'paged' => $paged,  
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part('parts/bl`enter code here`ogloop');

    }


    if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi'))
        {
            wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) );
        }

    wp_reset_postdata();

} else {
    echo 'no posts here';
}
```

This will show paging and work like a charm for you.

Comment: Thank you @prashant, I prefer to do it myself without extra plugins, or at least create my own plugin

Answer (score 0):

I guess that I figure it out
the solution is to edit the WP_Query args to be a custom number which is not same as site posts_per_page

```
'posts_per_page' => 11, // 13, or 20 ...
```

instead of

```
'posts_per_page' => get_option('to_count_portfolio'),
```

Why ? I've no idea, maybe the are some kind of conflict
someone can try it and see if that solution works with him/her same as me